# How to calculate molar mass using the ideal gas law?

Tags: physical-chemistry, gas-laws

> It is found that 250 ml of a diatomic gas at standard temperature and pressure (STP) has a mass of 1.78 g. What is the diatomic gas?

How can this question be solved? I know that I am supposed to use the ideal gas law

$$pV = nRT,$$

but am not sure how to apply it to this question.

Answer (score 6):

You can first use the ideal gas law to calculate $n$:
\begin{align}
pV &= nRT\\
(\pu{101325 Pa})(\pu{0.250 l}) &= n(\pu{8.314 J K-1 mol-1})(\pu{273 K})\\
\end{align}

Solving for "$n$" gives $n = \pu{0.0111577 mol}$.

Now we use the connection between mass $m$, amount of substance $n$, and molar mass mass $M$:

\begin{align}
  M &=\frac{m}{n}\\
  n &=\frac{m}{M}\\
  \pu{0.0111577 mol} &= \frac{\pu{1.78 g}}{M},
\end{align}

which gives a molar mass of $M = \pu{159.53 g mol-1}$.

Looking at the Periodic Table, we can identify the diatomic gas as being bromine gas ($\ce{Br2}$), which has a molar mass of $\pu{159.8 g mol-1}$.

Comment: The question reads "at standard temperature and pressure (STP)"; therefore the pressure should be $p=100\,000\ Pa$ and not $p=101\,325\ Pa$; however, that's a common mistake in homework questions. Another mistake in this question is that bromine is a liquid at STP.